# Can anyone tell what this cronjob does?

Tags: linux, cron

I am learning about cronjob and I found this piece of code in one project which fetches record from twitter,

the code goes like this:

```
#0 * * * * cp /vold/www/Abcd/log/twitter_feed_item_aggregator.log vold/www/Abcd/log/twitter_feed_item_aggregator.log.backup; > /vold/www/Abcd/log/twitter_feed_item_aggregator.log
```

Can anyone explain what this piece of code does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm... Copies a twitter agregator log each hour, and then clears it.

This part `0 * * * *` means 'every 0 minutes'. Minute 0 is when a new hour starts.

This part `cp /vold/www/Abcd/log/twitter_feed_item_aggregator.log vold/www/Abcd/log/twitter_feed_item_aggregator.log.backup` obviously copies the log to a backup.

This part `> /vold/www/Abcd/log/twitter_feed_item_aggregator.log` outputs the *output* of no command to the file, thus clearing it.

Comment: thanks how can i remove this cronjob if i type crontab -r it will remove all other job also but i want to remove only this cronjob

Comment: crontab -e to edit the crontab (and either comment out with # as pointed out by Douglas or simply remove the line). Good practice to backup the crontab first with crontab -l > crontab.backup as it is possible to lose the crontab if your system runs out of disk space when saving after a crontab -e

Comment: should i restart the cron after removing the cronjob from crontab

Comment: i think not, but it won't hurt :)

Answer (score 2):

The hash at the start of the line comments out the line so it does nothing. Without that it would do as @playcat says.

Comment: I think it wasn't there in the beginning :), but you're right.